# Why does the Intel Atom processor need so much thermal dissipation compared to similar ARM processors

Tags: embedded, microprocessor, thermal, intel

When looking at cases designed around the [Intel NUC Atom-based board](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/nuc-kit-de3815tykhe.html) it seems they put a lot of effort into thermal dissipation (i.e. the entire case is basically a [big heatsink](http://www.minipc.de/image_db/Akasa_Newton_T.jpg)). Of course, these cases are fanless and the logic goes that since there is no fan you need to get rid of heat by some other means - hence the huge heatsink.

However, my smartphone contains a very comparable processor (Qualcomm Snapdragon) and my phone contains neither a fan nor that huge heatsink. The TDP for the [Intel Atom](http://ark.intel.com/products/78476/Intel-Atom-Processor-E3815-512K-Cache-1_46-GHz) is advertised as 5W whereas it seems the Snapdragon is closer to 2.5W .

My questions are:

- Is the Snapdragon's thermal design just so vastly superior to that of the Intel Atom processor or is there some benefit to the Intel Atom that I'm missing?
- Also, assuming that the 5W/2.5W numbers are accurate, does that justify the huge difference between cooling solutions?
- Are there any other solutions (for running a linux-based appliance) that I should look at that have solid industrial support but neither require a huge heatsink nor a fan?

Comment: What frequency are they clocked at?

Comment: The Atom is around 1.5GHz whereas the Snapdragon runs at about 2.5GHz. This is probably the max clock speed so I'm assuming those processors are running at a slower clock most of the time.

Comment: In the title, you say "similar ARM processors"; but the Intel Atom is not an ARM architecture but rather x64-86 so you're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: What I mean is that the processors have similar capabilities even though they run on different architectures. Paraphrasing the question: Why does running bare boned linux require so vastly different thermal solutions for these two different types of processors?

Comment: TDP follows the intended platform. The E3xxx Atoms are for embedded systems and thin clients. Z3xxx Atoms are what Intel has to compete with the Snapdragon line.

Comment: can't answer for sure, but my rough guess is that intel and x86 in general is quite old stuff and they use some old design features even in modern processors and probably this old stuff has some problems with heat, but it's too late and too expensive to re-build this to be more efficient(and not affect something else during renovation). Modern ARM processors are better designed maybe in this case, they could see on other ICs heating problems and make a good solution. I might be very wrong, but eh, just guessing, good answer will follow from those who know exactly :)

Comment: one is designed for lower power the other isnt.  implement your designs with fewer gates and fewer state changes, etc...intels are historically microcoded with vliw or risc architectures so you cant really say new vs old they both have new technologies.  Another factor is that arm doesn tmake chips, intel does so arms designs have to be producable everywhere, etc, they work harder on their ip where intel only has to be built by intel, closed source, etc.  the chip is the product not the rtl only has to be good enough to make the chip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The atom processor is based on an older architecture, plus it has to carry the baggage of being PC-compatible. So it is more complicated to implement therefore requiring significantly more transistors for similar capabilities. I believe the term RISC came after the x86 was well on its way.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to try to answer why one might want to add extra cooling, although I can't answer why it was done in this case.

For CMOS, from a low power design perspective, a lower temperature means several things:lower leakage and higher maximum speed. The maximum speed improvement allows you to reduce the supply voltage which further improves both leakage and active power.

A bigger heatsink may also mean that you can do away with the fan. Fans are often the cause of early failure.

Additionally, a lower temperature means longer lifetime. And NBTI which I won't go into details about, is also temperature dependent.

Summing up, adding extra cooling to a design means a potential improved quality.

However, you can't compare the quality of two designs by the size of their heat sinks!